# Composition and Bad Encryption

Tags: combinatorics

Just for fun in our computer science class, I wrote a silly quick encryption program that simply xor's each byte with a password. I added a 16 bit checksum to the end of the encrypted bytes as the sum of all the original bytes. I added this to check if the password was correct during decryption instead of displaying garbage data.

I soon realized afterwards that this was horrendous from a security point of view. For example, if I only encrypted one byte, that byte could instantly be determined by looking at the checksum. Similarly, if I encrypted two bytes, there would only be up to four different possibilities to choose from that add up to the checksum.

Essentially, I wanted to know just how bad this encryption was, and what the probability of guessing the original text was by finding how many combinations are possible given the amount of bytes and checksum.

I found what I think the solution is on Wikipedia here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics) with the formula found at the  bottom of the page under "Number of compositions": For A-restricted compositions, the number of compositions of n into exactly k parts is given by the extended binomial (or polynomial) coefficient

$$\binom{k}{n}_{(1)_{a\in A}}=[x^n](\sum_{a\in A}x^a)^k$$

I am asking here because I do not know how to interpret or evaluate the formula. My math teacher is also unsure of what the formula means. Any help explaining what the formula means and how to evaluate it would be great!

I also think that this formula would stop being accurate after the checksum exceeds 255 because a byte cannot hold a value greater than that. Any input or solutions for this is also welcome!

Comment: It’s a good thing that you didn’t have enough rep to post an image of a formula. Don’t do that. Use MathJax to format mathematical expressions. You can find a tutorial and quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The notation on the right-hand side looks like that for selecting the coefficient of $x^n$ from a generating function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $[x^n]f(x)$ represents the coefficient of $x^n$ in the power series of $f(x)$. If $f$ is already a polynomial or formal power series, this is of course simply the coefficient of $x^n$ in $f$. This notation is quite common when working with generating functions, as often occurs in combinatorics. E.g., $[x^n]e^x=1/n!$ and $[u^m](1+u)^s=\binom s m$. So, the formula in the article defines ${\binom k n}_{(1)_{a\in A}}$ to be the coefficient of $x^n$ in the polynomial $\left(\sum_{a\in A}x^a\right)^k$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is still not clear to me what the $(1)_{a\in A}$ subscript indicates in the formula or the $a\in A$ implies in general... Where is this A series coming from?

Comment: See section 2 of [the referenced paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL16/Eger/eger6.pdf) for more details.